# Find files with similar names in a folder using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a requirement of selecting xml files from a folder of same ID's.
E.g. There are files with name

1. S-000001-0-0.xml
2. S-000001-0-1.xml
3. S-000001-0-2.xml
4. S-000001-0-3.xml
5. S-000001-0-4.xml
6. S-000002-0-0.xml
7. S-000003-0-0.xml

From 1 to 5 Xml belongs to one ID and 6,7 belongs to different ID.
My requirement is to select files of type 1 to 5 together and move to a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Glob_Patterns-1) like so:

```
mv S-000001-*.xml dir-to-move-to
```

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks For the quick reply.Yes your suggestion will work but only for one ID.There are thousand of different ID's.I need to move all the files.If I will use the above method it will only move one similar ID not all the ID's

Comment: @user32885 - Oh, I see -- your ID is the second part of the filename; that didn't seem clear from your question. See my edit, it should do what you want.

Comment: No Chris,ID is the first part of the filename.This is customer ID for a bank employee.We receive file by the name S-083344-0-0.xml,if this customer has a joint account then we will receive files by name S-083344-0-0.xml,S-083344-0-0.xml,S-083344-0-2.xml.Hope now You have got my point.So i have to move files of joint account as well as single ID account.Single ID will not have 2nd part as -1,-2,-3,it will be simply S-083884-0-0.xml.The ID has fixed 6 characters after S-

Comment: @user32885 I'm confused. You say that the "ID has fixed 6 characters after S-", but you also say that the ID isn't the second group... when the group after S- *is* the second group.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in `ls S*.xml | egrep -o '[0-9]{6}' | sort | uniq`; do mkdir -p /tmp/$x; cp S-$x-* /tmp/$x/.; done
```

This will create a folder ID (for each ID) in /tmp and then will copy there all files with the same ID.

You can replace `cp` with `mv` if tests are ok.

I assumed that ID has 6 digits and all other numbers are smaller.

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: egrep is throwing error,egrep :illegal option --0

Comment: please give a real file name example, for those above it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/old/directory -name 'S-??????-?-?.xml' -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -r0 mv -vt /path/to/new/directory
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the second portion of the filename is the ID, so this will move too much.